# Wrong assembly file location after conversion from .NET 4 to .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I convert some project from .NET 4.x to .NET 6.0.

All my projects produce an exe.

If I print `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`, I get `myproject.dll` and not `myproject.exe`.

If I print `$(OutDir)` in PostBuild event, I get `myproject.dll` and not `myproject.exe`.

I try with a new simple project exe in .NET 6.0, and again I get the `.dll` instead of the `.exe`.

I know I can use `Environment.ProcessPath`, but I certainly missing some configuration in the `.csproj`.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only difference between a dll and a exe is the exe has a MAIN method as the entry point.

Comment: My program start fine in debug mode and the .exe file exist after compilation.